# Getting a credit card having recently moved to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-cards

I am trying to get a credit card and I have been in the UK for less than 12 months. I am employed, registered to vote and I pay my taxes here.
I checked for answered questions regarding this topic and information from other sources. There are mainly two standard answers:

- Articles often recommend getting a "Credit Builder Card" to build your credit score. The problem being they generally require 2 to 3 years of previous addresses in the UK, with the exception of the Amazon one that requires 12 months.
- [How to go about building credit history in the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-to-go-about-building-credit-history-in-the-uk)
  The top answer of this question recommends getting a "Secured Credit Card". However, the link the person points to no longer exists and a search for "Secured Credit Cards UK" returns "Credit Builder Cards".

Is it possible to be eligible for one before 12 months?

Comment: Do you have an account with a UK bank? If so, that would be a logical source to try first. You could also try using this tool https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/eligibility/credit-cards/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq_Sz1t6-6gIV8IBQBh1hWQ5eEAAYAyAAEgICpfD_BwE

Comment: @Traveller I checked with my bank, but at least online, they require 3 years of previous addresses in the UK. I will try to speak with someone at my local agency Thanks for the tip, the tool is currently unavailable, but they seem to accept a short period of residency.

Comment: @gstorto I know it's difficult at the moment but talking to someone in person can often have better results, especially in a case like this.